# Qt: Best mechanism to capture and pass signals

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwidget

I have a class extending `QWidget` class and this class uses a Ui class generated by QtDesigner. Something like following:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
   signals:
            void pushButtonClicked();
   // ....
   private:
            Ui::MyUi ui;

}

MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
    ui = new Ui::MyUi();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Now lets suppose there is a `QPushButton * pushButton` field inside `Ui::MyUi`. The UI for this widget has no complex business logic.

Now it is required that whenever `pushButton` is clicked this widget should emit a signal (lets call it `pushButtonClicked()`. Now the only way I can imagine this to be achieved is to:

1. connect `clicked()` signal of `pushButton` object to a local slot and emit signal `pushButtonClicked()`from there.
2. Install `MyWidget` as  mouseEventFilter for `pushButton` and handle it inside `MyWidget::mouseClickedEvent`

Are there other options? Like somehow letting Qt framework to use 'MyWidget::pushButtonClicked()' instead of `pushButton->clicked()`

In the project I have many scenarios like this where such signal passing is needed from the wrapper classes like `MyWidget`, which wrap/abstract the UI by aggregation or inheritance. In general which is considered the best approach for better design, code reuse esp. when the project is at nascent stage and it is not known which of these UIs might need complex business logic in the future.

Please note that extending QPushButton is not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect signals directly =)

```
connect(pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(pushButtonClicked()));
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have known better.